# Error in BizTalk 2020 Release Pipeline DevOps

Tags: devops, biztalk, azure-devops-server

I’m following the Microsoft official tutorial in order to configure BizTalk 2020 with DevOps, and the release pipeline is deploying the MSI “properly” but at the end I’m getting the error message:

> “No mapping was made between account names and security identifiers.”

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

this a biztalk related conf issue. look at this thread :

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f2fae62-0f68-4ba9-ba6a-be9e973e4cfc/biztalk-server-2010-no-mapping-between-account-names-and-security-ids-was-done?forum=biztalkgeneral